# Error : Unable to resolve dependencies. 'entityframework 6.4.4' is not compatible with 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' constraint EntityFramework(= 6.2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

When I try to update my Entity Framework version in VS 2019, I get this error :

> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'entityframework 6.4.4' is not compatible with 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' constraint EntityFramework(= 6.2.0)'

I've tried to delete my package `EntityFramework.fr` (the language) but when I do the update, it shows up again in the packages folder.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1525

Comment: @HansPassant Hello, I've already saw this topic and it didn't work for me

Comment: Maybe you can try to downgrade EntityFramework.

Comment: @KyleWang Downgrade it ? it isn't not risky ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your solution explorer, right click references, manage nuget packages, go to "installed" tab and uninstall your language pack from EntityFramework (EntityFramework.fr for example), then update again.

Worked for me